# Testing Mustache Templates with JavaScript/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine, mustache

#### The Problem

My pair and I are debating and felt the SO community should weight in.

1. Should we test our view (Mustache) templates?
2. If so, how can we best test them?

#### What we have tried

Since, in the case of Mustache, our view templates are *mostly* logic-less we have chosen not to test them. However, we are starting to use inverted sections and functions where it seems we *should* be testing.

The tests we have written we render the view templates with dummy data, then use jQuery to assert the HTML contains the dummy data as expected.

#### The Question

Testing this way seems rather cumbersome and as such fails a cost/benefit analysis.

We are wondering if there is a better (faster or tools) way to test these view templates?